# QT QMediaPlayer Widget causes small white window

Tags: c++, qt, video, qmediaplayer

I want to add a videoplayer inside of a qtabwidget in my .ui form file. When the program is ran (Windows 8) the program window is a small white box (not what my .ui form is) and the video plays (you can hear it). Also, if I comment out everything after “ui->Information->addTab(videoWidget, “video”);” the program’s UI loads like normal and the new tab is created “video”, however nothing works cause the mediaPlayer code is commented out. This is the code for the media widget:

mainwin.h

```
private:
    QMediaPlayer * mediaPlayer;
```

mainwin.cpp

```
ui->setupUi(this);
mediaPlayer = new QMediaPlayer();
QVideoWidget *videoWidget = new QVideoWidget();
ui->Information->addTab(videoWidget, "video");
mediaPlayer->setVideoOutput(videoWidget);
mediaPlayer->setMedia(QUrl("link"));
mediaPlayer->play();
```

Can someone help? Thanks!

EDIT: Looking over examples from qt I noticed "mediaPlayer(0, QMediaPlayer::VideoSurface)" when the window is being created if I were to do this I would get:

```
Project::Project(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
mediaPlayer(0, QMediaPlayer::VideoSurface),
ui(new Ui::Project)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
```

This results in a few errors, "error: expression list treated as compound expression in mem-initializer [-fpermissive] mediaPlayer(0, QMediaPlayer::VideoSurface)", "warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]", and "error: cannot convert 'QMediaPlayer::Flag' to 'QMediaPlayer*' in initialization".

Comment: Probably not related to your main problem: you're redefining mediaPlayer in your constructor.

Comment: @AlexP so the second line in mainwin.cpp does not need to be there?

Comment: By putting `QMediaPlayer * mediaPlayer =`, You were re-declaring mediaPlayer in your constructor, which will effectively hide your class variable. I edited your question text (you'll see it after another user approves it) to show you how to change it, because it's easier than describing it in the comments.

Comment: @Alexp alright I see what you did there. Thanks. My major issue is still unresolved though.

Comment: Yeah, I kinda figured this change wouldn't fix it. (Always worth a try, though, you know?) I'll look around a bit more and post an answer if I find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after embedding the complete QT media player example in my QT 5.5.0 project. After starting playing the video, a white box would show up in left-top corner.

I noticed that the player would actually make my application toolbar (partially) white, but if the toolbar was hidden, it would add the white box.

Since I did not need the toolbar, I fixed this by removing the toolbar
instead of hiding it.  In QT designer, right-click in the toolbar, then "Remove Toolbar ".